# Using JExcelApi to write BigInteger to xls with $ and , formatting

Tags: java, excel, xls, jxl, jexcelapi

I am trying to write values stored as BigDecimals e.g. 6789456123 to an xls file but I require the xls file to display $6,789,456,123 (As a currency with 0dp. I can do it as a string with this formatting however this ins't ideal). I am using [JExcelApi](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html#copying%20and%20modifying) and I am unable to figure out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you need to create a custom numberFormat http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: You can convert a BigDecimal to double with the method `.doubleValue()`. Changed example to meet your needs.

---

Try to create a custom NumberFormat like this:

```
NumberFormat dollarCurrency = new NumberFormat(NumberFormat.CURRENCY_DOLLAR + " ###,###,###.00", NumberFormat.COMPLEX_FORMAT);
WritableCellFormat dollarFormat = new WritableCellFormat(dollarCurrency);
n = new Number(column, row, myBigDecimal.doubleValue(), dollarFormat);
s.addCell(n);
```

You can also read up on many other example here: [jxl demo](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/jxl/demo/Write.java.html)

Comment: As far as I can see this doesn't work as I am dealing with BigDecimals. Number has no constructor for (int,int,BigDecimal,WriteableCellFormat)

Comment: @Rudder_NZ the 3rd paramaters is a double. use .doubleValue of method of Bigdecimal. So in your case pass: myBigDecimal.doubleValue() as the 3rd param

Comment: That worked thanks. For some reason I thought I had already tried that and it hadn't worked.